# How to iterate through pre built dataset in PyTorch?

Tags: view, pytorch, dataset

I am trying to iterate through the data in the KarateClub dataset in Pytorch. My goal is to view the dataset as rows and columns, like in a table. Although there are pre built attributes like *dataset.num_features*  and *dataset.num_classes*, there seems to be no built-in function to display the data present in the dataset. When I write the code given below

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import KarateClub
dataset = KarateClub()
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    print(dataset[i])
```

I get the following output, but it does not show the data present
`Data(x=[34, 34], edge_index=[2, 156], y=[34], train_mask=[34])`

Answer (score 1):

The dataset you are reffering is a social graph model from the article

> An Information Flow Model for Conflict and Fission in Small Groups, 1977

This is graph in PyTorch Geometric (this framework also used for GNN) and typically accessed via this API https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/introduction.html#data-handling-of-graphs

So you can only access graph features like this:

```
dataset.x, dataset.y, dataset.edge_index
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So am I right in understanding that a Graph based dataset cannot be converted into a tabular format?

Comment: Graph and tabular dataset are completely different structure.
To be true, graph can be converted to tabular by using e.g.adjacency matrix and vice versa. 
But if you are looking for PyTorch buildin datasets, begin from this page https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html